# do I need to pay money again when I request another certificate?

Tags: iphone, ios, certificate

I deleted my certificate file in my Provision Portal page, then I wrote a email to apple to apply a new certificate, 10 days past I received no answer, do I need to pay another 99usd to get a new certificate? or Could I upload my old certificate file to Privision Portal?

Thanks

zhimakaimen

Comment: To me this seems to be off-topic-ish, although I am not sure where it would be suitable - superuser.com maybe?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to email Apple to create a new certificate. Just go to http://developer.apple.com/iphone , log in and click on the iOS Provisioning Portal.

Comment: I had a similar problem and used the provisioning portal to generate another one.

Comment: The provisioning portal has been (mysteriously and non-obviously) semi-down a few times over the last several weeks, something that I've either experienced first-hand or have colleagues on Twitter complaining about it. I say "semi-down" because most of it works but certificate creation seems to be messed up. An Apple person that I follow on Twitter noted that they were aware of a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to generate a new CSR (Certificate Signing Request) in KeychainAccess.app, and you submit that to the iOS Developer Portal.  You'll have to also generate new provisioning profiles for all of your apps, deleting the old ones in the developer portal.  They are all referenced to your old developer certificate.

Comment: No, not until you expire from the program after 1 yr